# why there is an extra record stored in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i created a csv to mysql database importer.
Code-

```
<?php 

include_once("connection.php");


if(isset($_POST["import"])){
$filename =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    while(($column = fgetcsv($file,10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO datasets (name,email,phone) values('" . $column[0] . "', '". $column[1] . "', '" . $column[2] . "')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlInsert);

        if(!empty($result)){
            echo "CSV data imported into database !";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error importing data into database ...";
        }
    }
    
}
}

?>
```

And form code is -

```
<form class="form-container my-5" action="backend/api.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="import" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But, the record should looks like this-
[image]

So, i marked red , the unexpected data. I cant find out why it shows like that? any errors in code?

Comment: There are no extra records. your code stored i the database the entire contents of the csv file

Comment: The first row of your csv is the header, you would need to skip it.

Comment: @RolandStarke skip it ? is there a way to make it not show in database?

Comment: Ah yes, I meant skip the insert, so that its not in the database. You could for example before your while loop add: `fgetcsv($file,10000, ","); //read first line and throw away to skip header` or inside your while loop do `if($column[1] === 'email') { continue; }`

Comment: @Dharman yea i will change it now .. just testing someting real quick. Anyway thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip the header row of your CSV file. Just don't execute the SQL statement for the first row.

Your corrected code should look something like this:

```
<?php

include_once "connection.php";

if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        
        $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO datasets (name,email,phone) values(?,?,?)');

        $headerRow = true;
        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== false) {
            if ($headerRow) {
                $headerRow = false;
                continue;
            }
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $column[0], $column[1], $column[2]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        echo "CSV data imported into database !";
    }
}
```